# Fix div at the bottom of a *positioned fixed sidebar* only if there is enough vertical space available

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed sidebar and I want to stick a div to the bottom of it only if there is enough vertical space available.

If there is not enough vertical space the fixed div should not overlap the previous element, instead it should be *on the flow* and generate a scrollbar instead.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the div that refers to your sidebar and apply a minimum height to it in your CSS.

```
#sidebardiv{
    min-height: XXXXpx;   <--- Where the number of pixels is at least the 
}                             combined height and margins of all 3 boxes.
```